# android getTag error

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, simplecursoradapter

Can someone explain why this is crashing? I am doing it the exact same way twice. My logcat says its the int FN line so if I comment out the int FN line, it will continue on. But I need to get both tags, not just one.

I set my ID in my Resources

```
<resources>
<item type="id" name="fromNumberTag" />
<item type="id" name="contactImageTag"/>

</resources>
```

I set my tags in my adapter.

```
    // SET OUR DATA FROM OUR CURSOR
    String phone_number = list.getString( list.getColumnIndex("phoneNumber"));
    from.setTag(R.id.fromNumberTag,list.getString(list.getColumnIndex("contactId")));
    contactimage.setTag(R.id.contactImageTag, phone_number);
```

Then I try to get the tags. (THIS IS WHERE IT IS CRASHING AT)

```
     int cid = Integer.parseInt(listText.getTag(R.id.fromNumberTag).toString());
     int fn = Integer.parseInt(listText.getTag(R.id.contactImageTag).toString()); // LOGCAT SAYS THIS LINE IS WHERE ERROR OCCURS
```

My logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at myapp.myapp.MainActivity$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:272)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the tags on two different objects (`from` and `contactimage`), but trying to get the tags from only one object (`listText`). Maybe you set one tag on the wrong object or read one tag from the wrong object?

Comment: Thank you, your comment made me look back at what I was doing. I am still new, so didn't understand I had to assign them both the the same object and just use the ID to separate them.  Changed them to `// SET OUR TAGS
        from.setTag(R.id.fromNumberTag,list.getString(list.getColumnIndex("contactId")));
        from.setTag(R.id.contactImageTag, phone_number); `  and working great.